# Customizing InfoPath Hyperlink Addresses

Tags: c#, .net, hyperlink, infopath

I have a repeating table, and I want one of the fields to be a hyperlink.  There doesn't seem to be any way to set the address of the hyperlink based on a formula, though.  I want to be able to make the address equal to some base URL concatenated with one of the other fields in the table. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private string ChangeXmlContent(Uri url, XmlDocument xdoc, string description)
{
    XmlNode group91 = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//my:group91", NamespaceManager);

    group91.SelectSingleNode("//my:Url1", NamespaceManager).InnerText = url.ToString();
}
```

Fast & easy

Answer (score 0):

I have used the xpath function concat(my:field2,my:field3) with the hyperlink field.   you will have to type in the xpath expression yourself as the designer for some reason will not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a custom field (as a Hyperlink field). I then populated the field with the corrected address (FULL ADDRESS!!! That was my problem. No relative URLs!!)

When my form loads, I have a rule that sets the hyperlink field like so:

- RootURL is a custom variable I have already defined in an XML
  resource file.
- I concatenate the RootURL with the final string, and
  apply that to a second custom field. I called it "Edit Record" in the
  example below.
- I use that second custom field (Edit Record) as the source for 
  my hyperlink object on the form.

**Rule:**
[image]

**Hyperlink on my form:**
[image]